# xterm -ls -rv not reversing colors for blackbox

Tags: ubuntu, unix, virtualbox, xterm

Right now when I run my xterm -ls -rv I still get a blackbox window with a grey background and black characters. Normally when I ran -rv it would reverse the colors making it have a black background and white characters.

**File:** *~/.blackboxrc*

```
session.styleFile:    ~/.blackbox/myawesomestyle
session.menuFile:     ~/.blackbox/menu
```

**File:** *~/.blackbox/menu*

```
[begin](My Super Menu)
    [exec](Xterm) { xterm -ls -rv }
    [restart](Restart)
    [exit](Exit)
[end]
```

**File:** *~/.blackbox/myawesomestyle*

```
*button.pressed.appearance: sunken solid
*button.pressed.backgroundColor: darkgrey
*button.appearance: parentrelative
*button.foregroundColor: black

*backgroundColor: rgb:dd/dd/d7
*color1: rgb:dd/dd/d7
*color2: rgb:ee/ee/e7

*font: Bitstream Vera Sans-9

*borderColor: black
*borderWidth: 1
*marginWidth: 2

menu.title.appearance: flat solid border
menu.title.backgroundColor: grey
menu.title.foregroundColor: black
menu.title.textColor: black
menu.title.alignment: center
menu.title.font: Bitstream Vera Sans-9:style=Bold

menu.frame.appearance: raised gradient border
menu.frame.textColor: black
menu.frame.foregroundColor: grey40
menu.frame.disabledColor: darkgrey
menu.frame.alignment: left

menu.active.appearance: flat solid border
menu.active.backgroundColor: rgb:77/77/74
menu.active.foregroundColor: white
menu.active.textColor: white

rootCommand: bsetroot -solid rgb:aa/aa/aa

slit.appearance: raised solid
slit.backgroundColor: rgb:aa/aa/aa
slit.marginWidth: 3

toolbar.appearance: raised gradient border
toolbar.alignment: center
toolbar*textColor: black
toolbar.label.appearance: parentrelative
toolbar.clock.appearance: parentrelative
toolbar.windowLabel.appearance: parentrelative

window.title.focus.appearance: raised gradient border
window.title.focus.color1: rgb:66/66/63
window.title.focus.color2: rgb:88/88/84
window.title.unfocus.appearance: raised gradient border

window.label.focus.appearance: parentrelative
window.label.focus.textColor: white
window.label.unfocus.appearance: parentrelative
window.label.unfocus.textColor: darkgrey
window.label.marginWidth: 1

window.button.focus.appearance: parentrelative
window.button.focus.foregroundColor: white

window.button.unfocus.appearance: parentrelative
window.button.unfocus.foregroundColor: darkgrey

window.handle.focus.appearance: raised solid border
window.handle.unfocus.appearance: raised solid border

window.grip.focus.appearance: raised solid border
window.grip.focus.backgroundColor: rgb:77/77/74
window.grip.unfocus.appearance: raised solid border

window*alignment: center
window.font: Bitstream Vera Sans-9:style=Bold
window.handleHeight: 8
```

I made sure to check if my configurations were being used by adding another item to the menu list and it worked.

Does anyone have any theories or potential troubleshooting mechanisms to figure out what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally there was no problem at all. My style file was somehow changed to black background and I was using -rv thinking that it wasn't working.